# What's the difference between 同然 and 同様?

Tags: word-choice, definitions, synonyms, word-usage

As in the title, what is the difference between these two?

dictionary.goo.ne.jp says:

> [同然](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/156262/m0u/%E5%90%8C%E7%84%B6/): 同じであること。また、そのさま。同様。
>
> [同様](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/157033/m0u/%E5%90%8C%E6%A7%98/): 同じであること。ほとんど同じであること。また、そのさま。

and on the 類語 page these two are listed under [one entry](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/thsrs/16964/m0u/%E5%90%8C%E7%84%B6/):

> 「同様」「同然」は、「同じ」「一緒」より、差異についての基準が緩い場合にほぼ似たような意味合いで用いられる。

yet, according to the table at the bottom there, [their usage seems to differ](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/thsrs/16964/m0u/%E5%90%8C%E7%84%B6/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd translate 同然 as "so similar that it can now be considered X" or "as if it is X". It states there is effectively no difference between the two. E.g. 夫婦も同然の二人、もはや勝ったも同然だ.

同様 would be more generally, "in the same manner to X", e.g. 炭酸と同様の作用を有する、操作は先ほどと同様です

> 同性婚は認められていないものの、夫婦と同様の税制が適用される
>   ... same tax rules are applied

.

> 同性婚は認められていないものの、夫婦同然の税制が適用される
>   ... same tax rules are applied, such that there is essentially no difference between same-sex vs hetero-sex marriage.

`彼のと同然の靴` would be weird as you would be stating "the shoe can be considered to be essentially his". When expressed more naturally, this will be `彼の物であるも同然の靴`.

Comment: hmm.. according to your explanation, do i understand correctly that 同然 relates to *things* and 同様 relates to situations, state of things, etc?

Comment: @AyanamiSan: Don't think so, you can for example say 諦めたも同然だ ("you've effectively given up!" or "There is effectively no difference from having given up")

Comment: ok, with this example i think i understand, and it's still what i'm expressing in english as *thing* (i'm not a native english speaker and i don't know how to express it better) thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: The particle も seems to be acting a little funny near 同然

Answer (score 0):

According to my 広辞苑, 同然 is "same to the prevoius word", 同様 is "both are the same".
You can start a new paragraph with 同様に, but cannot with 同然に.
This is because 同然 requires the  previous word within the same paragraph.
Since 同然's usage is limited, 同然 is likely to be considered an idiom.